# Error Message: Node.exe is not a valid Win32 Application

Tags: node.js, deployd

I have installed **www.deployd.com** on my Windows-XP PC for learning purposes. The book am studying ask me to execute the following command at the prompt ::

```
> dpd create sportsstore
```

but i get the following error message

```
Node.exe is not a valid Win32 Application
```

What must i do to rectify this error?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

**The `node.exe` it is complaining about is inside the the tools folder of Deployd. It is like this
`C:\program files\Deployd\tools\Node.exe is not a valid Win32 Application`**

Comment: did you install the right version of node for the book?

Comment: is your version of windows 32bit? and is the version the book came with 64bit?

Comment: @KevinB thanks for you reply. I have updated my question. The node.exe it is complaining about is inside the "...Program Files /Deployd/tools" folder.

Comment: @KevinB The book does not specify the kind of OS you should do the installation. It just asks you to download the Deployd app and install it, whether it is on 32bit or 64bit, it doesn't matter. But my version of Windows-XP is 32bit

Comment: it does matter, because if your windows is 32bit you cant' run 64bit node.

Comment: @KevinB OK. I downloaded the 32bit version of NodeJS and replaced the other version and it seems everything is working now. Thanks alot Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is usually an indicator of trying to run a 64bit application in a 32bit OS.

The solution is to change the version of node to the 32bit version. Be careful to choose the same version as your tutorial to avoid any conflicts.